# API and declaration of functions/classes in Java

Tags: java, api, code-documentation

I'm reading the first chapter of *Algorithm* (and the first two chapters of *Introduction to Programming in Java*) by Sedgewick and Wayne. I don't understand what an API means. The following is an excerpt from the book:

> [image]

An example is given as follows:

> [image]

Here are my **questions**:

- Is an API part of the Java codes?
- How is an API different from declaration of functions/classes?

Comment: API stands for **a**pplication **p**rogramming **i**nterface, here is a good description: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface). In general API is code that is used by other programmers to, for example, create a final product. It is kind of an utility tool. For example an API for mailing offers easy to use methods to setup and send mails, without having the full knowledge of mail protocols. So you could view the whole Java standard library as API, I would see *library* as good synonym there.

Comment: More precise one could talk of API as the part of a library that specifies the behavior, so interfaces and documentation for example. Having that you could have different implementations of one API specification that all fulfill the same overall result.

Comment: This concept doesn't apply to just Java

Comment: @Zabuza: thanks for your comments. So the answer to my first question would be "yes"? What would you say about the second question?

Comment: I would say an API consists of the whole set of classes and functions, together they form an API. But more precise the API is just the description of the input and output, it does not necessarily declare **how** one must implement this description. This perfectly matches the concept of `interface`s. So you could for example have someone that creates the API by just creating hundreds of **interfaces** and their **documentation**. Then another team could write implementations for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An API is the interface to a code library. It consists of the objects and methods used to interact with a library.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. A system can somewhat be compared to a puzzle. For example, a website might consist of the WordPress blog engine and a database (MariaDB). If both are considered as puzzle pieces, the shape of their corresponding side must match for them to fit together. Instead of having interjambs and blanks, WordPress speaks SQL and MariaDB also speaks SQL. If the SQL dialects match, then the line between the pieces is the same, and one piece can be inserted next to the other, so both pieces have a compatible *software interface*. Instead of being short lines though, APIs are much more complex.

Most APIs contain lots of functions/methods which must have corresponding behaviors on both sides. Technically, the API is the "shape of the line" between the client and the library, as Kirby wrote. But the term has become extremely confusing because it has gained numerous other senses. Often, *API* means a description of the line's shape, i.e. a ***specification of an API***, which could be a document describing the objects in the library, or a set of Java interfaces. In that sense, then yes, an API (specification) can be "part of the Java codes".

Technically, the API differs from declarations of classes the same way that the shape of a puzzle piece edge differs from the puzzle piece itself; SQL is very different from MariaDB. That being said, in actual jargon, *API* has come to be used to refer to implementations of an API. This is particularly true in the web. When people talk about *web APIs*, they often refer to *services* offering an API implementation to consumers.

In short, the sense of *API* has been largely/excessively extrapolated, and nowadays the answer to your questions **depends on the context**. If we make a parallel between software interfaces and APIs, in the previous example, current jargon could use "API" to refer to either:

1. the Structured Query Language itself (the interface)
2. the ISO documents specifying the SQL standard(s) (an interface specification)
3. a SQL-compliant DBMS engine, like MariaDB (an implementation; proscribed but common)

**In the context of Java, an API is often a small package which contains abstract classes** which are implemented in one or more packages implementing that API.